# Pass array of strings using kSOAP2

Tags: android, soap, soap-client, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I need to update an app that is using kSOAP2 to make requests. So, now this is the xml of the operation:

```
<bios:login>
  <auth>
    <parameter1>example1</parameter1>
    <parameter2>example2</parameter2>
    <parameter3>example3</parameter3>
  </auth>
</bios:login>
```

The operation before didn't have the `auth`, now I have to add it. The `login` is the operation itself, and then the parameters.

I did this with a custom class that implements KvmSerializable. Basically it has the parameters as attributes (I won't pass the class code to keep this simple).

Then I passed that to the envelope like this:

```
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(searchRequest);
```

How should I do it now to encapsulate the parameters inside the "auth"?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you have a class that will serelize to

```
<bios:login>
  <parameter1>example1</parameter1>
  <parameter2>example2</parameter2>
  <parameter3>example3</parameter3>
</bios:login>
```

but need to encapsule that in `auth`. In that case you can add a class that has your current calss as property.

If you want an array (where all parameter names are the same) you can use this `PropertyInfo`

```
PropertyInfo elementType = new PropertyInfo();
info.setName("auth");
info.setType(PropertyInfo.VECTOR_CLASS);
elementType.setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);
elementType.setName("parameter");
elementType.setNamespace(Constants.NAMESPACE);
info.setElementType(elementType);
```

If you have an arraay with variable number of parameters and those parameters needs to have different names (counting up) than this will not help you.

---

By the way it would have been simpler, through not as short, if you had posted your `KvmSerializable` and how you created searchRequest, including the xml that will currently output.